# Sidekiq return value of a delayed method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backgroundworker, sidekiq

I use Sidekiq to run a method delayed in controller (meanwhile I use Redis to update a progress bar). This method call a server, retrieve the data, do some manipulation and calculation; then can take a while.

For example, I have this method:

```
data_and_status = MyModelName.delay.retrieve_data(params[:tags], "preview", current_user, params[:from], params[:to])
```

This method should return the data manipulated, but doing in this manner `data_and_status` is an hash (I guess that is the Sidekiq-job-id).
The data returned is very large, doing some caching with Redis is unfortunately out of question.

How can I retrieve a `return value` of a delayed job (method)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You say that the data returned (from your asynchronous job) is very large, and relaying it via Redis is out of the question.  Well, your sidekiq job runs in a different process, possibly even on a different server, so you must find some inter-process way to transfer the data - if not your message queue (Redis), then the database.

For example:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply! Then you suggest to use the DB to store somewhere a flag that indicates the "status" of the job? And when finished retrieve the result data from db or from a file in /tmp?

Comment: If you only want to check the status of the job, you could use a sidekiq plugin to track that: see https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-tell-when-a-job-has-finished